# Identify the group $(28\mathbb Z + 20\mathbb Z)/20 \mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

This is a homework problem for an abstact Algebra course.

Identify the group $(28\mathbb Z + 20\mathbb Z)/20 \mathbb Z$.

I did this just by looking at individual elements of $(28\mathbb Z + 20\mathbb Z)$, and what happens to them after modding out by $20$.

Elements of the "numerator" (not sure the right word) take the form $28i + 20j$ for integers $i,j$. However, since we are modding out by $20$, the additive factor of $20j$ doesn't change things. Therefore, by looking at $28i$ for $i\in \mathbb Z$, we see that

$28 \equiv 8 \mod 20$,

$56 \equiv 16 \mod 20$,

$84 \equiv 4 \mod 20$, etc.

So we get that this group looks like $\{0,4,8,12,16\}$.

Equivalently, I think this looks like $4\mathbb Z / 20 \mathbb Z$. In other words, multiples of $4$, except multiples of $20$ are "equal to zero."

In general, I possibly see a pattern that $n \mathbb Z / m \mathbb Z$ is given by $\gcd(m,n)\mathbb Z / m \mathbb Z$.

Is this correct?

(since this is homework, hints or corrections are also fine, instead of a full answer).

Comment: Perhaps the second isomorphism theorem could help.

Comment: Your answer is right, although perhaps you could get there in a prettier way. Your general pattern seems suspicious:  does this make sense, and/or did you intend something else?

Comment: in general you can prove $\langle h+m\mathbb{Z}\rangle=M\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ where $M=\gcd(h,m)$

Comment: additionally, you can prove that $n\mathbb{Z}+m\mathbb{Z}=M\mathbb{Z}$ with $M=\gcd(m,n)$

Comment: Thanks - I got the same answer using the 2nd isomorphism theorem. I ended up with $28\mathbb Z / 140 \mathbb Z$ which is isomorphic to $4\mathbb Z / 20 \mathbb Z$. I see now too that my general statement doesn't entirely make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $H,K\le G$ and one of them is normal,  $HK$ is a subgroup.

The only subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ are the cyclic $n\Bbb Z.$

It's easy to see that $20\Bbb Z+28\Bbb Z\cong 4\Bbb Z$.  For we have that there's $a,b$ such that $a20+b28=4,$ by Bezout.

So we have $4\Bbb Z/20\Bbb Z\cong \Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z.$